# Updating duplicate student Information in django

Tags: python, django, view, model, upload

I have a bunch of CSV files that I have made to upload to a django model. 
1. Created a view to upload the csv
2. Separated the fields and added them to a variable
3. Called the update_or_create() method to add the information into the model.

The problem that I am facing is getting django to update the old row instead of creating a new one. If a student has failed in the first year but passes the next year, the old marks have to be updated.

I am trying to filter() with the Register Number of the student and Class to narrow it down. IF there is a student with for instance AAAAAA1111 from BA 1 SEM, and they gave the exam in 2016, 2017 and passed in 2018, the last result has to update the old result.

I am enclosing two documents which i used. One is the 2016 result and the second is the 2017 repeaters csv. LINK TO FILES: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_5cHRKNYdLBYWLhPw_Z4dn-VgX14Amw2

This what my view looks like

```
    template = "uploadstudent.html"
    data = {}
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, template, data)
    # if not GET, then proceed

    csv_file = request.FILES["csv_file_student"]
    if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
        messages.error(request,'File is not CSV type')
        return redirect(request,template)

    data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')    # setup a stream which is when we loop through each line we are able to handle a data in a stream
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
    #loop over the lines and save them in db. If error , store as string and then display
    for fields in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
        data_dict = {}
        data_dict["registerNo"] = fields[0]
        data_dict["studentName"] = fields[1]
        data_dict["result"] = fields[2]
        data_dict["totalMarks"] = fields[3]
        data_dict["studentClass"] = fields[4]
        data_dict["exam"] = fields[5]
        data_dict["subject1"] = fields[6]
        data_dict["subject1Marks"] = fields[7]
        data_dict["subject1Result"] = fields[8]
        data_dict["subject2"] = fields[9]
        data_dict["subject2Marks"] = fields[10]
        data_dict["subject2Result"] = fields[11]
        data_dict["subject3"] = fields[12]
        data_dict["subject3Marks"] = fields[13]
        data_dict["subject3Result"] = fields[14]
        data_dict["subject4"] = fields[15]
        data_dict["subject4Marks"] = fields[16]
        data_dict["subject4Result"] = fields[17]
        data_dict["subject5"] = fields[18]
        data_dict["subject5Marks"] = fields[19]
        data_dict["subject5Result"] = fields[20]
        data_dict["subject6"] = fields[21]
        data_dict["subject6Marks"] = fields[22]
        data_dict["subject6Result"] = fields[23]
        #data_dict["subject7"] = fields[24]
        #data_dict["subject7Marks"] = fields[25]
        #data_dict["subject7Result"] = fields[26]
        #print(data_dict["studentClass"])
        #print(data_dict)
        studentInfo = studentResult.objects.filter(studentClass__icontains=data_dict["studentClass"], registerNo__icontains=data_dict["registerNo"]).update_or_create(
                registerNo=data_dict["registerNo"],
                studentName=data_dict["studentName"],
                result=data_dict["result"],
                studentClass=data_dict["studentClass"],
                totalMarks=data_dict["totalMarks"],
                exam=data_dict["exam"],
                subject1=data_dict["subject1"],
                subject1Marks=data_dict["subject1Marks"],
                subject1Result=data_dict["subject1Result"],
                subject2=data_dict["subject2"],
                subject2Marks=data_dict["subject2Marks"],
                subject2Result=data_dict["subject2Result"],
                subject3=data_dict["subject3"],
                subject3Marks=data_dict["subject3Marks"],
                subject3Result=data_dict["subject3Result"],
                subject4=data_dict["subject4"],
                subject4Marks=data_dict["subject4Marks"],
                subject4Result=data_dict["subject4Result"],
                subject5=data_dict["subject5"],
                subject5Marks=data_dict["subject5Marks"],
                subject5Result=data_dict["subject5Result"],
                subject6=data_dict["subject6"],
                subject6Marks=data_dict["subject6Marks"],
                subject6Result=data_dict["subject6Result"],
                #subject7=data_dict["subject7"],
                #subject7Marks=data_dict["subject7Marks"],
                #subject7Result=data_dict["subject7Result"]
                )



    #return render(request, "listuploads.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create

You should split the data you pass to the `update_or_create` into your `kwargs` and the `defaults` where defaults is a dictionary containing the new values and the `kwargs` should be the `unique identifiers` of your student, for example the `registerNo`

something like this:

```
studentInfo, created = studentResult.objects.update_or_create(registerNo=data_dict["registerNo"],
          defaults={
                'studentName':data_dict["studentName"],
                'result':data_dict["result"],
                'studentClass':data_dict["studentClass"],
                'totalMarks':data_dict["totalMarks"],
                 # and so on....
           })
```

I removed `filter(studentClass__icontains=data_dict["studentClass"])` this line only looks for the student in the current class but as you stated you want to have the older marks updated, you only have to ensure that the import is done in the correct order.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm quite dumb at understanding the documentation and spent two days trying to make sense of it before posting. The solution worked perfectly.